# Azure Media Services JobState is no longer an enum

Tags: azure-media-services

Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.Models.JobState **can no longer be used as an enumeration**.  This is a breaking change from 2.0.0 version of the package.

Assembly: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

```
public static bool IsRunning(this JobState state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case JobState.Canceled:
        case JobState.Canceling:
        case JobState.Error:
        case JobState.Finished:
            break;

        case JobState.Processing:
        case JobState.Queued:
        case JobState.Scheduled:
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from AMS team:
As noted in the [release notes for 2.01](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nuget.org%2Fpackages%2FMicrosoft.Azure.Management.Media&data=02%7C01%7Cv-jamapu%40microsoft.com%7C21f892dd2ab447a4aab208d67684bed4%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636826709861740042&sdata=6bHq2BYAX2j%2BtS75v%2BtKpknvRR3nMKJ8tVRQz7cTx1w%3D&reserved=0):
            * Enumeration extensibility was re-enabled. This feature was enabled in the preview versions of the SDK and got accidentally disabled in the GA version.

This mean this was breaking change where the caller can’t do a switch as the JobState as it was changed to be extensible which means the JobState values went from const to static read only definitions. So the caller needs to change their code from switch to if/else.

Thanks,

Jaime Mapula
Support Engineer 
Azure Media Services